# Why New measure dax not showing tables, only showing measures

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure, powerbi-custom-visuals

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRNb4.png)

I wanted to create new measure using other columns from different tables but measure dax is not showing other table. Except for when using sum function when it shows other tables other than just measures

Comment: You gave the answer in your posting already: a measure is a scalar that needs aggregation over a column. A “direct” reference as in your screenshot does not work as Power BI cannot decide which row to pick from.

Answer (score 0):

In measure calculation you cannot just input the table columns, you should combine with formula:

1. for data column, use formulas such as SUM, AVERAGE, MAX, MIN usually SUM but it depends on your actual needs;
2. for text column, use SELECTEDVALUE, MAX, MIN;
3. for date column, use formula related with date such as DATEDADD,DATESBETWEEN, FIRSTDATE, LASTDATE;
4. if you want to input the table as filter, then use formulas such as FILTER, CALCULATETABLE.

Comment: @ Sia: … **3. for date column, use formula related with date such as DATEDADD,DATESBETWEEN, FIRSTDATE, LASTDATE;** … if I remember correctly, these functions return also a table with a single column

Comment: @Anonymous Yes ahhh does he/she need several columns...